# Plotting a histogram with a conditional

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I'm trying to make a histogram out of data in a file that looks like this:

```
#Column 1   Column 2
#
0.0300      0.2126
1.0000e-4   0.0104
6.0000e-3   0.1299
1.0000e-4   8.0600e-3
1.0000e-4   0.0105
0.0190      0.2204
6.0000e-3   7.4900e-3
1.0000e-4   0.0952
6.0000e-3   7.4200e-3
1.0000e-4   0.0131
0.0190      0.3062
0.0190      0.2561
0.0300      0.9748
0.0300      0.9406
0.0300      0.0139
1.0000e-4   0.0281
0.0300      0.3625
1.0000e-4   0.0945
0.0300      0.5650
1.0000e-4   0.1045
6.0000e-3   0.2362
1.0000e-4   0.0180
1.0000e-4   0.1366
1.0000e-4   0.0195
0.0300      0.4652
0.0190      0.3505
0.0300      0.5146
0.0190      0.4319
6.0000e-3   0.2054
6.0000e-3   0.2377
0.0300      0.5281
1.0000e-4   0.1128
6.0000e-3   0.0623
```

If I use the code:

```
n=20    #number of intervals
max=0.03 #max value
min=0    #min value
width=(max-min)/n        #interval width
hist(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)+width/2.0

plot 'data' u (hist(\$1,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes lc rgb "blue" lt 1 lw 0.5 notitle
```

I get the right histogram:

[image: right histo]

but if I use the conditional line:

```
plot 'data' u (hist((\$2<=0.5?\$1:1/0),width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes lc rgb "blue" lt 1 lw 0.5 notitle
```

I get this:

[image: histo wrong]

You can see that `gnuplot` isn't adding the lines correctly but plotting them as separate columns instead.

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Is this part of a bash "here" script?  Otherwise, I can't figure out why you're escaping your "`$`"

Comment: Yes, it's a script. In any case that's not really the issue here because escaping the `$` gives no problem with the first `plot` line (the one with no conditional in it)

Comment: escaping the `$` gives problems when you try to paste the stuff into a gnuplot script to run ;).  No worries though.  I've added 1 solution to this (quite interesting) problem though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is a symptom of how gnuplot treats "missing" data.  With respect to missing data, the following are actually slightly different:

```
plot 'data' u 1:2 w lines    #connects lines across missing records
plot 'data' u 1:($2) w lines #doesn't connect lines when a missing record is encountered
```

I suspect you're seeing a slightly different symptom of this design decision.

Unfortunately it makes the typical gnuplot data-filter useless here :-(.  Fortunately, your condition is easy to move into `awk`:

```
plot "< awk '{if ($2 <= 0.5) {print $0}}' test.dat " u (hist($1,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes lc rgb "blue" lt 1 lw 0.5 notitle
```

Now gnuplot sees only the data you want it to (since it doesn't see any NaN values, so it doesn't create any new counters).

Comment: Please tell me if I'm understanding the way you wrote that line. For what I can tell it means: _"if a value in column $2 of file 'test.dat' is <=0.5 then count it; otherwise dismiss it"_. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the awk script just removes lines where the value of the element in column 2 is larger than 0.5. (in `awk`, `$0` is the full line, so it reads like this:  `if (column2_value <= 0.5) then print full_line`.  I think that in `awk` `print $0` is pretty much equivalent to just a bare `print`, but I prefer the former as I think it is slightly more explicit about what is happening (as long as you know what `$0` stands for ...

Comment: @Gabriel -- No problem.  It's a pleasure as always.  I like answering gnuplot questions because I like gnuplot.  :)